# Automating things other than web browsers

Tags: automation

So for all you test automaters who have to automate tests which use other than (or in addition to) web browsers (for example, Java windows, etc), which cannot be accessed via Selenium: What tools(s) do you use?  Say, for instance, you need to click an OK on a java swing object, or fill in a text box.  (The example picture is just an example to give the idea of what I mean.  I am not trying to automate connecting to the VPN).  We would most likely be interfacing to it with java.

[image]

Comment: Never heard about Windows Application Driver? https://github.com/microsoft/WinAppDriver

Comment: Hey can you tell me about its "inspect.exe"?  I read documentation but still am unclear.  Right now we use test complete and find objects using names like the following:
""Name=[\"SwingObject\"](\"JPasswordField\", \"\", 0);".  Will inspect.exe return this sort of info? Object Spy in Test Complete used to but now it gets only the outermost object